# How to inject UserManager in the ConfigureServices method of startup.cs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, configuration

How do I pass UserManager instance to called PhysicalFileAttachmentService service?

here are the codes

```
public class PhysicalFileAttachmentService : IFileAttachmentService {
    private readonly ILogger<PhysicalFileAttachmentService> _logger;

    private readonly string _contentRootPath;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public PhysicalFileAttachmentService(ILogger<PhysicalFileAttachmentService> logger, string contentRootPath, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _contentRootPath = contentRootPath;
        _userManager = userManager;
    } }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddSingleton<IFileAttachmentService>(s => new PhysicalFileAttachmentService(s.GetService<ILogger<PhysicalFileAttachmentService>>(), s.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, ?? )); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to Inject other services which is being passed as parameter for the constructor first like this

```
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
  .AddTransient<iuserrepository>(sp => new UserRepository(connectionString, sp.GetService<ilogger<userrepository>>()))
```

before injecting those services to the PhysicalFileAttachmentService  hope you get the idea from the code